# Dictionary containing all nodes and edges from graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx, graph-theory

I need to build a graph from a given list of edges like this:

```
Edges = ["cc-gc","cc-da","ee-cd","ee-bg","de-bg"]
```

from list of edges above, how do I get the graph like this:

```
graph = { "cc" : ["gc","da"],
      "gc" : ["cc"],
      "da": ["cc"],
      "ee": ["cd", "bg"],
      "cd": ["ee"],
      "de": ["bg"],
      "bg": ["de", "ee"]
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `networkX` we can build a graph by splitting the strings in the list and using [`nx.from_edgelist`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.convert.from_edgelist.html), and look for the [`nx.neighbors`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.neighbors.html) of each node:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_edgelist([s.split('-') for s in Edges])

graph = dict()
for node in G.nodes():
    graph[node] = list(nx.neighbors(G, node))
```

---

```
print(graph)

{'cc': ['gc', 'da'],
 'gc': ['cc'],
 'da': ['cc'],
 'ee': ['cd', 'bg'],
 'cd': ['ee'],
 'bg': ['ee', 'de'],
 'de': ['bg']}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [networkx.convert.to_dict_of_lists](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert.to_dict_of_lists.html#networkx-convert-to-dict-of-lists):

```
import networkx as nx

edges = ["cc-gc", "cc-da", "ee-cd", "ee-bg", "de-bg"]

G = nx.from_edgelist([s.split('-') for s in edges])

print(nx.convert.to_dict_of_lists(G))
```

**Output**

```
{'bg': ['ee', 'de'],
 'cc': ['gc', 'da'],
 'cd': ['ee'],
 'da': ['cc'],
 'de': ['bg'],
 'ee': ['cd', 'bg'],
 'gc': ['cc']}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the format is `node1-node2` for all list elements a simple for loop does the trick

```py
graph = {}
for edge in edges:
  node1, node2 = edge.split('-')
  if node1 in graph.keys():
    graph[node1] += [node2]
  else:
    graph[node1] = [node2]
  if node2 in graph.keys():
    graph[node2] += [node1]
  else:
    graph[node2] = [node1]
```

Comment: What error do you have? 
The only one I could imagine is coming from your variable name `Edges` instead of `edges` in my code

Comment: From E = ["a-b", "b-c", "a-c"], I get {'a': ['b', 'c'], 'b': ['c']}
However, it should be {'a': ['b', 'c'], 'b': [''a',c'], 'c' : ['a', 'b']}

Comment: My bad, I thought the edges were oriented. I've edited my answer accordingly